# How to make a tuple from a list in scala?

Tags: scala, collections, immutability

I have list say - 
`List("aa","1","bb","2","cc","3","dd","4")`

How to make a list of tuples with even and odd positions :
`(aa,1),(bb,2),(cc,3),(dd,4)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope it will help.

```
val list = List("aa","1","bb","2","cc","3","dd","4")

val tuple =
list.grouped(2).map { e =>
  (e.head,e.last)
}.toList
```

Comment: Note if we `map` before `toList` we only have to iterate once, so `list.grouped(2).map(...).toList` instead of `list.grouped(2).toList.map(...)`, because `grouped` returns an `Iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @maria Galic. And your answer gave me more way to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

We should consider the case of oddly sized lists, for example, `List("aa","1","bb","2","cc","3","dd")`:

- Should we return `List((aa,1), (bb,2), (cc,3), (dd,dd))`?
- Should we drop the last element and return `List((aa,1), (bb,2), (cc,3))`?
- Should we indicate error is some way, perhaps with `Option`?
- Should we crash?

Here is an example of returning `Option[List(String, String)]` to indicate error case:

```
def maybeGrouped(list: List[String]): Option[List[(String, String)]] =
  Try(
    list
      .sliding(2, 2)
      .map { case List(a,b) => (a, b) }
      .toList
  ).toOption
```

Comment: This would explode if we removed e.g. "4" from the List. I prefer @Mahesh Chand's answer (and btw, `sliding(2, 2)` is the same as `grouped(2)`).

Comment: @slouc Perhaps better to explode than give wrong answer such as `(dd,dd)` with `grouped`.

Comment: Could be, depending on the needs. But I'd prefer wrapping everything in an Option in that case, rather than exploding at runtime.

Comment: In my opinion, that looks much better! But again, depends on what the OP needed. Personally I'd keep it in an Option to indicate that there might be an error, unless I'm really fine with silently ignoring it and simply removing the last element (like in your solution).